# Какая разница между <тег>...</тег> и <тег/>

Tags: html

Есть ли разница в написании кода

```
<тег>...</тег> и <тег/>
```

кроме отсутствия элементов внутри? В html такой синтаксис работает со всеми элементами?

Примеры (верные и ложные):

```
<div></div> <div/> <input/> <input></input>
```

Comment: Второй вариант не существует. Откуда Вы это взяли вообще?

Comment: Конечно, не ко всем :) Изучите азы html

Comment: `input` запрещено открывать первым способом, а `div` запрещено закрывать вторым способом. Браузер просто проигнорирует такое закрытие и будет считать `div` открытым.

Comment: @Mike Water Есть пустые теги и вложенные. Это основное отличие ))) посмотрите информацию о строении разметки html https://puzzleweb.ru/html/2_elements.php и http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/sintaksis-html5

Comment: Говоря на народном языке, второй вариант используется когда элемент не поддерживает вложенных в себя тегов.

Comment: @andreymal например eslint сворачивает закрывающий див. а ещё браузеры воспринимают свернутый див нормально - он закрывается сразу.

Comment: @eri ваше утверждение легко опровергается простейшим примером https://jsfiddle.net/jvh1Ls7t/

Comment: @eri справедливости ради, в xhtml допустимы оба варианта, так как синтаксис xml не делает различий между разными тегами https://andreymal.org/files/xhtml-test/xhtml5-div.xhtml (jsfiddle не умеет в xhtml, поэтому пришлось файл на своём сайте делать — см. исходный код этого файла)

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант используется в jsx в том случае, если у тега нет дочерних узлов или контента. Но в самом html такого нет.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-children-with-jsx)

Comment: "Но в самом html такого нет.". Не правда. Закрывать одиночные теги не обязательно в HTML, но это не значит, что там такого нет.

Comment: Разве это считается валидным кодом?

Comment: да. Но опять повторюсь, в HTML5 - это ставить по желанию.